# Building an SSH Tunnel using Windows Services for Linux

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the following ssh command to open a remote session to my network and tunnel RDP through it. What I'm looking to do is open local port 3390 and have it forward out the remote end to 192.168.1.235:3389.

```
ssh -L 3390:192.168.1.235:3389 srv.my.org
```

I use a similar setup with putty that works fine.  Using Ubuntu/bash on Windows 10 (build 14393), I receive a `bind: Address already in use`.  The ssh session establishes, but not the tunnel.  I verified nothing is currently running on either port using `netstat -an |grep 3390`. Also ran `lsof -ti:3390` and received no results.

Comment: You probably want remote port forwarding, if you want your local 3390 port accessible on the `192.168.1.235`.

Comment: @Jakuje I may not be clear on the remote/local definitions. I added a bit on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Could you try to run  "lsof -ti:3390" to see what is using this port ?

Comment: @tobiasBora Thx. Done and added to question.  No results were returned.

Comment: Event if you run it as sudo ?

Comment: @tobiasBora yes.  Keep in mind this is a limited linux environment running within Windows.  I've used `netstat -an|findstr 3390` to verify the port is not in use under Windows

Comment: Hum... How did you set-up the linux environment under Windows ? Is you use instead Putty like this, does it work ? : http://klinkner.net/~srk/techTips/ssh-remote/

Comment: Using Windows Services for Linux (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about). 
And yes, putty tunnels work fine.  I suspect this is a feature of the way ssh is working under WSL. Was hoping to find some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with, by default, the system wanting to use IPv6.  If you force to IPv4 it will work.  Try one of these options:

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:3390:192.168.1.235:3389 srv.my.org
```

OR

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:3390:192.168.1.235:3389 srv.my.org
```